# Mobile Keyboard quebrando layout

Tags: bootstrap-4, layout-responsivo

Testando no mobile a responsividade do meu layout, reparei que ao clicar em um elemento `HTML` de entradas de dados (I), como por exemplo no meu caso o `<input>`, abre-se o keyboard do dispositivo (o qual isto é uma ação padrão).

Porém o keyboard está de certa maneira "levantando o container" onde se encontra este elemento `HTML` (`<input>`), assim quebrando completamente o meu layout.

- Porque motivo isto acontece?
- Existe um modo de "corrigir" isto? Caso sim, como proceder?

**Nota**

> Eu percebi que isto está acontecendo porque eu inseri `height: 100;` para centralizar o meu conteúdo no centro da tela, porém como eu posso centralizar o conteúdo no centro sem precisar utilizar o `height`?

Na figura abaixo utilizei um android da marca Asus, porém o que acontece aqui, acontece em todos os android do mesmo modo. Nesta figura podemos observar que ao clicar no `<input>` o keyboard é acionado e empurrando o container para cima, assim "empurrando" o meu layout (perceba onde vai parar a frase, embaixo do navbar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./dist/css/verification.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar py-4">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div><img id="navbar-main-logo" src="./dist/img/copa-dor-logo.png" alt="Copa Dor Hospital"></div>
                <div><span id="navbar-main-category-title">Verificação</span></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100" style="border: 0px red solid;">
            <div class="pb-3">
                <h6 class="font-weight-light text-secondary text-center">
                    Digite o código <br>
                    do e-mail que enviamos para você
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="py-4">
                <form>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="form-row px-4 px-md-5 pb-5">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-center rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 bg-light shadow-none" required autofocus style="font-size: 1.8rem;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-center rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 bg-light shadow-none" required style="font-size: 1.8rem;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-center rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 bg-light shadow-none" required style="font-size: 1.8rem;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-center rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 bg-light shadow-none" required style="font-size: 1.8rem;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control font-weight-bold text-center rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 bg-light shadow-none" required style="font-size: 1.8rem;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row px-4 px-md-5 pb-4">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary shadow-sm py-2 py-lg-3">VERIFICAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div><a href="#" class="btn mx-auto d-block text-primary" role="button">Reenviar Código</a></div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por acaso vc colocou position fixed em algum elemento dentro do header ou no próprio header?

Comment: @hugocsl não amigo, somente height: 100%; no html,body, main e no container e row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caros amigos, o problema que estava ocorrendo era com o seguinte `css`:

```
html, body, main {
    height: 100%;
}

<main>
    <div class="d-flex h-100"></div>
</main>
```

O que ocorria com o `css` acima era o seguinte... Ele criava uma `height` de `100%` tanto no `HTML`, `BODY`, `MAIN` e no meu `.D-FLEX`, e ai que esta o problema, criar todos esses height. Por isto ao clicar no `input` no celular de baixa resolução, onde não continha muito espaço, o mesmo "estourava" o layout.

Para fazer a correção eu fiz o seguinte:

- Removi todos os height
- Adicionei o `css` abaixo

`CSS`:

```
body {
    min-height: 85vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Com isto seria criado flexbox com alinhamento ao centro no `body`, sem acontecer a "explosão" do layout por falta de espaço...

**Nota**

> o `min-height` está como `85vh` por pura escolha minha, o mesmo pode ser `100vh`!